# Printer dialog preview and current page

Tags: printing

For some reason the "preview" and the "current page" entries have disappeared from the print dialog popup. This was working 100% until the other day, but today it is gone.

I have checked my logs and don't see that any updates have been applied to my printer driver (Brother HHL3270CDW, using the downloaded driver) or to CUPS.

Now, if I want to print only one page of a PDF I need to specify the page number.

Any ideas as to what is going on. This is on Ubuntu 23.10.

In response to 2 different responses: I am getting this using PDF display programs including atril, okular and xpdf. I used to get "print current page option", but that no longer shows up.

Comment: The "print dialog popup" from which ptogram? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: "if I want to print only one page of a PDF I need to specify the page number"  hasn't that always been the case?